# Avoid dot on ElasticSearch/OpenSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, regex-lookarounds, amazon-opensearch

I am new with ElasticSeach, and currently working with OpenSearch from AWS OpenSearch service. In Dev Tools, I have the following query:

```
GET _search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "handler_id": "[^_*\\-.;?#$%^@!`,/?+()~<>:'\\[\\]{}]*`"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "handler_id": "~([^.])*[A-Za-z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[0-9]{8}"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "handler_id.keyword": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The above query supposed to get all handler_id without special characters on it, and then also meet the `must` format. It works, but it always return this `handler_id = .MP4137879580`. I also tried regex `^[A-Za-z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[0-9]{8}(?![^.]+$)`, then `"~([^`.`])*[A-Za-z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[0-9]{8}"` to escape dot, but the id still showed up.

Please give me some pointer on how to troubleshoot this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**:

```
GET _search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "handler_id.keyword": "~([^.])*[A-Za-z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[0-9]{8}"
          }
        },
        {
          "regexp": {
            "handler_id.keyword": "[^_*\\-.;?#$%^@!`,/?+()~<>:'\\[\\]{}].*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "handler_id.keyword": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This was tested that on elasticsearch. Sorry, I am not using opensearch and have not plans to start, but it is trivial enough so it should work.

There are several problems in your query.

The first one is that by default, elasticsearch indexes each record twice - one time in an analyzed form and another time in non-analyzed form. The analyzed form is stored in `handler_id` and for your test string it is converted into `mp4137879580` (lowercase split by spaces with punctuation removed). In the `handler_id.keyword` your original string is indexed as is. So, when you use `handler_id` in regexp you are search these converted strings instead of original strings. So, the first fix is to use `handler_id.keyword` in your query.

The second issue is that `regexp` contains an extra back tick at the end, which doesn't match. Just remove it.

The third issue is that you are using double negative here. First you find all handler_ids that don't contain punctuation, and then you wrapping it into `must_not` essentially saying "I don't want any of these". So you need to with either move your regex into `must` or change your regex to **match** handlers with punctuation and keep it in `must_not`. I picked the first solution in my example.

Comment: Thank you so much! The keyword did work for my case. It's good to know more behind-the-scene on how elasticsearch works. Also I really appreciate you pointing out my mistake with double negative, such an obvious oversight on my part.